# Ember.js - CSS transition not always working

Tags: css, ember.js, ember-data, css-transitions, ember-cli

I'm using Ember.js with ember-cli and ember-data. Until now, development went quite smoothly but now I encountered an issue with css transitions which I can't solve myself.

I have a list. The list contains elements which have subelements. These subelements are also rendered as a list.

I fetch the data with ember-data from a REST API. After the data is received I want to fade in (css opacity) the list. But this does not work correctly. Sometime the transition is shown and sometimes not. I'm afraid it is a timing issue. So I added Ember.run.next to my code but it didn't help. When I add setTimeout with 1ms inside Ember.run.next it works like expected (at least on my computer). This feels quite weird. Here is my code I have so far. Every feedback appreciated.

controller.js:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  //...
  objects: []
  //...
  _pushToMatchings: function (response) {
    var tempArray = [];
    var pushed = false;
    for (var i = 0, length = this.get('objects.length'); i < length; i++) {
        pushed = false;
        var match = this.get('objects').objectAt(i);
        if (match.get('meta.items').objectAt(0) === response.get('meta.items').objectAt(0)) {
            tempArray.pushObject(response);
            pushed = true;
        } else {
            tempArray.pushObject(match);
        }
    }
    if (!pushed) {
        tempArray.pushObject(response);
    }
    this.set('objects', tempArray);
  },
  fetch: function() {
    var self = this;
    // find parent item
    this.get('store').find('item', id).then(function (item) {
        self._pushToMatchings(Ember.Object.create({
            meta: {
                items: [id],
                isLoading: true,
                label: item.get('label')
            },
            content: []
        }));
        self.set('isOpen', true);
        // child object
        self.get('store').find('child', searchParams).then(function (result) {
            (function (resultPtr) {
                Ember.run.next(function () {
                    setTimeout(function () { // @todo why do we need timeout here? whitout there is no fade out with opacity in css possible
                        resultPtr.set('meta.isLoaded', true);
                    }, 1); // 1 is enough but give spinner some time otherwise it looks ugly
                });
            }(result));
            result.set('meta.label', item.get('label'));
            self._pushToMatchings(result);
        }, function (error) { /* ... */ });
    }, function (error) { /* ... */ });

  }
}
```

controller.hbs:

```
<div>
    {{item-list close="close" elements=objects }}
</div>
```

item-list.js

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    elements: [],
    actions: {
        close: function () {
            this.sendAction('close');
        }
    }
});
```

item-list.hbs

```
<div class="items-list__buttons">
    <i class="icon-close_32" {{action "close" }}></i>
</div>
<div class="items-list__content">
    {{#each matching in elements}}
        <div class="items-list__item">
            <h2>{{t "items.offers" }} {{matching.meta.label}}</h2>
            {{spinner-element hideEvent=matching.meta.isLoaded }}
            <div {{bind-attr class=":items-list__box matching.meta.isLoaded:items--fadeIn" }}>
                {{#each item in matching.content}}
                    <div>
                        <!-- Render details of item -->
                    </div>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.items-list__box {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 150ms ease 100ms;
}

.items--fadeIn {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: can you duplicate this on jsbin?

Comment: @Kalman: I could try to build a jsbin, the problem is, that I use our REST API... right now we are in development phase and I don't want to expose it to public. I could use some fixture for ember data but this isn't the real setup... At the first glance, does my code make sense? And should it basically work?

Comment: You can always use mockjax to get this into jsbin like in this example - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mipuwa/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: also, you might want to take a look at https://github.com/ef4/liquid-fire and  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8aF-7-_cE8

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ember.run.later, works same way than setTimeout.

```
Ember.run.later(this ,function(){
     resultPtr.set('meta.isLoaded', true);
}, 100);
```

I'm not sure but this is neccesary because the div would be render with the class "items--fadeIn" that the transition wouldn't occur. I've done this way and worked for me, just try incrementing the time a little.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, but for others receiving a similar issue:

Your problem is that Ember is re-rendering your entire list of items in your `{{#each` because every time something changes you are giving it an entirely new array of objects, instead of changing the properties of the objects in the array. What you need to do is to define your array of objects and manipulate their properties so that only the objects that change get re-rendered.